# VMware Infrastructure Web Access 2-CPU Limit?

Tags: cpu-usage, vmware-server

I am running VMWare Infrastructure Web Access 2.0.

I have several VMs running on 24 core machine.

I just looked at the most resource-intensive VM and found it is running using only 2 CPU cores of the 24.

When attempting to change it (VM is off), the picklist doesn't go above 2.

What limits this? Is there a way to change it?

Comment: What edition of vSphere do you have?

Comment: @GregL The OP isn't even using vSphere...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as though you're describing the [VMware Server 2.0 product](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_server/2_0) from 2009, not VMware vSphere or ESXi.

If that's the case, this product has been [end-of-life and support](https://serverfault.com/questions/149669/vmware-server-end-of-life-where-to-go-now) for at least 5 years. You shouldn't be using it today.

As for the guest VM configuration, VMware Server 2.0 only allowed you to allocate 1 or 2 vCPUs to a guest. There are no options for more virtual processors unless you move to another virtualization product.